# AngularJs - Find relational information in two arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm getting two json arrays from an api. Data Examples:

Serie type:

```
[
    {"Id":1,"BetTypeId":1, "NameEng":"Win"},
    {"Id":2,"BetTypeId":1,"NameEng":"Draw"}
]
```

Bet type:

```
    [
        {"Id":1,"NameEng":"3-Way Result","SportId":1    
        {"Id":2,"NameEng":"Double Chance","SportId":1}
    ]
```

As you can see, Serie type objects has BetTypeId. But i need to remote Bet type object from array there is no serie type for it.

I have tried looping in bet type array but i don't how do i filter in serie types.

What are the steps to achieve this?

Comment: Please try to better explain what you have and what you want to have, it is unclear what your problem is. Also, how is that related to angular?

Comment: I need to loop in BetType array. Find SerieType objects referring to BetType object and remove BetType object if there is no SerieType referring to it. I'm using Angular to do this. @floribon

Comment: You could use a nested foreach and splice out elements that match on your BetType

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array of Serie type and collect all `BetTypeId`'s like this:

```
var betIds = serieType.map(function (serie) { return serie.BetTypeId; });
```

Now you only have to loop though the BetType array and check if there is id for it in the `betIds` array we've got already:

```
betType.filter(function (bet) { 
    return betIds.indexOf(bet.Id) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: If you `splice` the array within the loop you will create an offset between `i` and the actual index. You should use `Array.filter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array this way:

```
betTypesArray = betTypesArray.filter(function(bet) {
  // If a seriesType item references this bet, keep it
  return seriesTypeArray.some(function(serie) {
    return serie.BetTypeId === bet.Id;
  });
});
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scenario in which you can see how to use `filter` to *filter* matches between two arrays. Do some reading regarding those functions [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var things = [
  {"id": 123, "name": "thing name"},
  {"id": 456, "name": "second thing name"}    
]

var foo = [
  {"id": 333, "thingId": 123},
  {"id": 111, "thingId": 787},
  {"id": 222, "thingId": 456}
]

foo = foo.filter(function (foo) {
  return things.some(function(thing){
    return thing.id == foo.thingId;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

See [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/f1j6q52k/)

```
var serie = [
    {"Id":1,"BetTypeId":1, "NameEng":"Win"},
    {"Id":2,"BetTypeId":1,"NameEng":"Draw"}
];

var bet =  [
         {"Id":1,"NameEng":"3-Way Result","SportId":1},
         {"Id":2,"NameEng":"Double Chance","SportId":1}
    ];

var result = jinqJs()
                    .from(serie)
                    .join(bet)
                        .on(function(left, right) {return (left.BetTypeId == right.Id);})
                    .select('Id', 'BetTypeId', 'NameEng', 'SportId');
```